# CSS grid - How to stop extraneous text from creating an auto row?

Tags: css, css-grid

I am trying to style some pre-existing content and I can't edit the HTML. There is a random  '&nbsp' in the code that is causing CSS grid to create a new row. How to stop the auto row when there is no html or class to target?

Edit: Some rows have 2 items and some have 3.

```css
td.product-name {
     display: grid;
     grid-template-columns: 60px 3fr;
     grid-template-rows: auto;
     grid-template-areas: " left righta " " left rightb " "left rightc";
         grid-auto-flow: dense; 
     border: 1px solid;
}
 td.product-name span {
  
 border: 1px solid;
 }
.product-image {
grid-area: left;
}
 .product-name {
     grid-area: righta;
}
 .product-quantity {
     grid-area: rightb;
}
 .variation {
     grid-area: rightc;
}
```

```html
<table>
<tr class="cart_item">
  <td class="product-name">
    <span class="product-image"><img width="50" height="50" src="https://i.imgur.com/1o3KcN6.png"></span>
    <span class="product-name">Product 1</span>
    &nbsp; <- remove the row created by this nbsp;
    <span class="product-quantity">QTY 1</span>
    <span class="variation">var 1 EDIT: This row doesn't always have a value.</span>  
  </td>
  <td class="product-total">
    <span class="amount"><bdi><span class="woocommerce-Price-currencySymbol">$</span>48</bdi>
    </span>
  </td>
</tr>
<tr class="cart_item">
  <td class="product-name">
    <span class="product-image"><img width="50" height="50" src="https://i.imgur.com/1o3KcN6.png"></span>
    <span class="product-name">Product 2</span>
    &nbsp; <- remove the row created by this nbsp;
    <span class="product-quantity">QTY 2</span>
     
  </td>
  <td class="product-total">
    <span class="amount"><bdi><span class="woocommerce-Price-currencySymbol">$</span>58</bdi>
    </span>
  </td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Please read the question, I can't edit the HTML.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option would be to make it an explicit row and give it zero height (`grid-template-rows: 1fr 1fr 1fr 0;`):

**UPDATE**: I've updated the answer based on the new information. Given that the `.variation` span may or may not exist, I've introduced the `has()` selector to check for this. Note that the `has()` selector doesn't have perfect support yet, though it's pretty good now in the latest browsers.

```css
td.product-name {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 60px 3fr;
  grid-template-rows: 1fr 1fr 0;
  grid-template-areas: " left righta " " left rightb ";
  border: 1px solid;
}

td.product-name:has(.variation) {
  grid-template-rows: 1fr 1fr 1fr 0;
  grid-template-areas: " left righta " " left rightb " "left rightc";
}
 
td.product-name span {
  border: 1px solid;
}

.product-image {
  grid-area: left;
}

.product-name {
  grid-area: righta;
}

.product-quantity {
  grid-area: rightb;
}

.variation {
  grid-area: rightc;
}
```

```html
<table>
<tr class="cart_item">
  <td class="product-name">
<span class="product-image"><img width="50" height="50" src="https://i.imgur.com/1o3KcN6.png"></span>
<span class="product-name">Product 1</span>
&nbsp;
<span class="product-quantity">QTY 1</span>
<span class="variation">var 1</span>  
  </td>
  <td class="product-total">
<span class="amount"><bdi><span class="woocommerce-Price-currencySymbol">$</span>48</bdi>
</span>
  </td>
</tr>
<tr class="cart_item">
  <td class="product-name">
<span class="product-image"><img width="50" height="50" src="https://i.imgur.com/1o3KcN6.png"></span>
<span class="product-name">Product 2</span>
&nbsp;
<span class="product-quantity">QTY 2</span>
  </td>
  <td class="product-total">
<span class="amount"><bdi><span class="woocommerce-Price-currencySymbol">$</span>58</bdi>
</span>
  </td>
</tr>
</table>
```

**UPDATE2**

Because `has()` currently doesn't work in Firefox, there is a compromise option that keeps every browser happy. It's not the perfect solution, but at least seems to provide an acceptable result in every browser.

```css
td.product-name {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 60px 3fr;
  grid-template-rows: 1fr 1fr auto 0;
  grid-template-areas: " left righta " " left rightb " "left rightc";
  border: 1px solid;
}
 
td.product-name span {
  border: 1px solid;
}

.product-image {
  grid-area: left;
}

.product-name {
  grid-area: righta;
}

.product-quantity {
  grid-area: rightb;
}

.variation {
  grid-area: rightc;
}
```

```html
<table>
<tr class="cart_item">
  <td class="product-name">
    <span class="product-image"><img width="50" height="50" src="https://i.imgur.com/1o3KcN6.png"></span>
    <span class="product-name">Product 1</span>
    &nbsp;
    <span class="product-quantity">QTY 1</span>
    <span class="variation">var 1</span>  
  </td>
  <td class="product-total">
    <span class="amount"><bdi><span class="woocommerce-Price-currencySymbol">$</span>48</bdi>
    </span>
  </td>
</tr>
<tr class="cart_item">
  <td class="product-name">
    <span class="product-image"><img width="50" height="50" src="https://i.imgur.com/1o3KcN6.png"></span>
    <span class="product-name">Product 2</span>
    &nbsp;
    <span class="product-quantity">QTY 2</span>
  </td>
  <td class="product-total">
    <span class="amount"><bdi><span class="woocommerce-Price-currencySymbol">$</span>58</bdi>
    </span>
  </td>
</tr>
</table>
```

So instead of an extra row at the bottom, there is just an empty cell on the right when there's no `variations` span.

Comment: That works, however I just realized that some items are 2 rows and some are 3, so I need to modify the question.

Comment: Okay, I've updated my answer based on the presence or non-presence of the `variations` span. It's all I can think of (short of using JavaScript). The only caveat is that support for the `has()` selector isn't perfect. https://caniuse.com/css-has

Comment: I've added a second variation that doesn't use `has()`, but it's a bit of a compromise for better browser support. Depends on how much you care about Firefox.

Comment: I like the has() version, not too concerned about Firefox.